# Search and Sort on the same page

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to implement sort and search to my items, so i **started with sort** and it works:

**Template**

```
    <button class="sort">Sort</button>

        {{#each cvs}}
                {{> Interviu}}
        {{/each}}
```

**JS:**

```
    Template.Interviuri.onCreated(function () {
        var self = this
        self.autorun(function () {
            self.sortOrder = new ReactiveVar(-1)
        })

    Template.Interviuri.helpers({
        cvs() {
            const instance = Template.instance()
            return Cvs.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: instance.sortOrder.get() } })
        },
    })
    Template.Interviuri.events({
        'click .sort'(event, instance) {
            instance.sortOrder.set(instance.sortOrder.get() * -1)
```

**Next i wanted to implement Search** on the same page. So the best way i could found was EasySearch. 
But using EasySearch, it means i must change the way my items are being displayed. And then **the sort doesn't work anymore.**

**Template**

```
    <div class="searchBox pull-right">
        {{> EasySearch.Input index=cvsIndex attributes=searchAttributes }}
    </div>

        {{#EasySearch.Each index=cvsIndex }}
            {{> Interviu}}
        {{/EasySearch.Each}}
```

**Collection**

```
CvsIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
    collection: Cvs,
    fields: ['name'],
    engine: new EasySearch.Minimongo()
})
```

**JS**

```
cvsIndex: () => CvsIndex,
```

> How can i have both search and sort working at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

With EasySearch you can use two methods on your index, namely `getComponentDict()` and `getComponentMethods()`.

With `getComponentDict()` you can access search definition and options:

```
index.getComponentDict().get('searchDefinition');
index.getComponentDict().get('searchOptions');
```

You also have the corresponding setters to change the search definition/option.

`getComponentMethods` has mehods like

```
index.getComponentMethods().loadMore(integer);
index.getComponentMethods().hasMoreDocuments();
index.getComponentMethods().addProps(prop, value);
index.getComponentMethods().removeProps([prop])
```

From that you can set your prop, say `index.getComponentMethods().addProp('sort', -1)` and then on the index definition, in your MongoDB engine, set the sort from that prop:

```
index = new EasySearch.index({
  // other parameters
  engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB({
    sort: function(searchObject, options) {
      if(options.search.props.sort) {
        return parseInt(options.search.props.sort); 
      }
       return 1;
    }
  })
});
```

See [EasySearch Engines](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/docs/engines/) for more info.